# SQL Query returns no results while using AND keyword

Tags: sql, sqlite, cs50

I am currently beginning with SQL using SQLite3 in CS50's Codespace. There is a simple problem regarding a query which I need to run.

I need to find out movies where BOTH Johnny Depp and Helena Bonham Carter were starring. MY query is as follows

```
SELECT title 
FROM movies
JOIN stars ON stars.movie_id = movies.id
JOIN people ON people.id = stars.person_id
WHERE people.name = "Johnny Depp" 
  AND people.name = "Helena Bonham Carter";
```

Now this returns 0 results. The query works when I only use one of the two names and remove the `AND` clause.

But as per my understanding the `AND` statement should work, is that the case or there is a lapse in my understanding?

Comment: Your WHERE clause is trying to filter on rows where the actor is 2 different people at the same time - which is obviously impossible and why you are getting zero records (it's filtering individual rows, not your recordset). You need to rethink your approach as you'll need to compare multiple records for each film/actor

Comment: How could `people.name` be both "Johnny Depp" AND "Helena Bonham Carter" at the same time? Think about it.

Comment: if you used OR insted of AND you also get your answer

Answer (score 0):

you could use exists and look for the existence of both actors.

```
SELECT title from movies
JOIN stars a ON a.movie_id = movies.id
WHERE exists (select 1 from people b
              where b.people.id = a.person_id
              and b.name = 'Johnny Depp')
AND exists (select 1 from people c
              where c.people.id = a.person_id
              and c.name = 'Helena Bonham Carter')
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also count up the actors that are Johnny Depp or Helena Bonham Carter and look for rows where the count is 2

```
Select title,
sum(case when p.name in ('Johhny Depp', 'Helena Bonham Carter') then 1 else 0 end) as cnt
from movies m
join stars s on s.movie_id = m.id
join people p on p.id = a.person_id
group by title
having cnt > 1
```